# Ruby on Rails - Chartkick gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

I am new to Ruby on Rails development. I am trying to plot a chart using Chartkick gem. Below is what I am trying to do.

I have a form with a POST method, and I am storing the params data in the instance variables in a method in a controller. I want to plot the data in the instance variables on a Chartkick graph.

Below is my view:

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
  <h1 class="display-4">LIGHTWAVE</h1>  
</div>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">HOME</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">USERS</a>
  </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">OPERATIONS</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<br/>
<div class="container">

   <%= form_with url: home_homepage_path, method: :post, multipart: true do |f| %>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-12">
            <b>OPERATION NAME:</b>
            <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Enter operation name", class: 'form-content form-content w-100 p-1' %>
            </div>
        </div>

     <div class="row">
        
        <div class="form-group col-6">
           <b>LOWER SPECIFICATION LIMIT (LSL):</b>
           <%= f.number_field :lower_specification_limit, placeholder: "Enter lower specificattion limit", class: 'form-content form-content w-100 p-1' %> 
        </div>
      
        <div class="form-group col-6">
           <b>UPPER SPECIFICATION LIMIT (USL):</b>
           <%= f.number_field :upper_specification_limit, placeholder: "Enter upper specification limit", class: 'form-content form-content w-100 p-1' %> 
        </div>

   
     </div>

      <div class="row">
         <div class="form-group col-12">
           <b>PROCESS TIME:</b>
           <%= f.text_field :upper_specification_limit, name: "user_specification_limit[]",  placeholder: "Enter process time. These values could be an array", class: 'form-content form-content w-100 p-1' %> 
         </div>
     </div>
  
  <br/>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Generate Plot', class: 'btn btn-block btn-outline-dark rounded-0' %>
  </div>
<% end %>

</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron border border-dark">
**<%= pie_chart @usl %>**
</div>
</div>
```

Below is the controller.

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def homepage
  @usl = (params[:upper_specification_limit]).to_i
  @lsl = (params[:lower_specification_limit]).to_i
  @design_time = @usl - @lsl 
  end


end
```

When I enter the values in the form, params get captured as expected. I have even checked the instance variables values using byebug gem. Everything is working alright but no graph is displayed in the view.

I have tested that Chartkick is working alright and is correctly installed.

I do not have any model and want to plot data straight from an instance variable to the graph. I am stuck on this and unable to find how to tackle this.

View Screencapture:

[image]

Embeeded Ruby to plot the chart:

```
<%= column_chart({us: @usl, ls: @lsl, des: @design_time}, empty: "No data", width: "800px", height: "500px") %>
```

**TEST 1:**- You can see that @usl value is 0 as I haven't submitted form.
[image]

I submit the form with values LSL - 30, USL - 100
[image]

We can see values are updated accordingly in console.
[image]

But in the view value of @usl is still 0
[image]

Comment: Data can be a hash, array, or URL...```pie_chart: {us: @usl, ls: @lsl}```.

Comment: Hello @dbugger, I have made the changes. However, I am unable to see anything on the chart. The instance variables do have the value and a POST request has also been made initiated as I can see on the server. Attaching the screen captures. Can you guide me on what mistake I am doing?

Comment: Where's the data for the pie chart?

Comment: That is what I am confused. I have successfully saved the param hash values in instance variables @usl and @lsl. I noted that @usl and @lsl values become 0 ```<%= @usl %>``` in the view.  However, in the console I am able to see the actual value of both instance variables. I think there is some issue in storing the param hash value in the instance variable due to which chartkick is also unable to access the actual value and thus noting is getting plotted.

Comment: Adding more supporting screen captures to this. I have added ```puts``` statement in my controller method to see value of instance variables before are after initiating a POST request. You can see that it's working as expected. But in the view for some reason instance variable value remains 0.

Answer (score 0):

Once I replaced the POST request to a GET request it worked. I had a thinking that since I am not posting anything to a database and also, I am not querying database, I don't need a POST request. Therefore, I tried using GET request in route and in form and it worked. Not sure if my thought process is right. Please correct me if I am not thinking correctly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).